# Spring batch hadoop - configure multiple mappers (MultipleInput)

Tags: spring, hadoop, mapreduce, spring-batch

I have a requirement to process two files having different formats. I am thinking of applying approach like below:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]),TextInputFormat.class,MapperOne.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[1]),TextInputFormat.class,MapperTwo.class);
```

How can I define multiple mapper in spring hadoop?

```
<job id="wordcount-job"
  input-path="${wordcount.input.path:/user/input/word/}"
  output-path="${wordcount.output.path:/user/output/word/}" 
  mapper="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.TokenizerMapper1"
  reducer="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.IntSumReducer" />
```

Please advice.

Comment: @Luca, can you please advice?

Comment: I only cleared SB tag because question doesn't seems to be specific for SB. If I was wrong let me know: I restore original tags and accept my apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Question is for SB only. how can configure MultipleInput if I want to use SB Hadoop? I know how can i achieve it in plain Java.